# Fences does not work on my Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, fences

I'm running on `Windows 7` and have tried installing `Fences` - it passes the installation but nothing happens afterwards - I don't get the fences initial window and cannot create fences.

Any idea what can cause this?

Important note: I'm using my company's laptop - so security policies might be prohibiting fences somehow - so if anyone has an idea on how to find out what it is, it will be also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptops security policies may definitely be affecting your ability to use Fences. Fences interacts with Windows Explorer on a low level, and changes the behavior of your desktop. A locked down machine may prevent those DLLs from registering or operating properly.

I have used Fences before on Windows 7 successfully, so I can definitely say it's not an OS issue.

Comment: Any idea if I can see it in any log? If I can find it I can (maybe) disable it